# Присвоение значения в тип long

Tags: java

Почему при присвоении `long n = 10 000 000 000 000;` IntelliJ IDEA выдает ошибку:

> java: integer number too large: 1000000000000.

хотя диапазон `long` от `-9223372036854775808` до `9223372036854775807`?

Comment: А если так: `long n = 10000000000000L;`?

Comment: То что слева от '=" означает что ссылка типа long, а вот присвоить вы собираетесь число которое является типом int не входит в диапазон int. Для long необходимо использовать в конце каждого значения 'L', ну а если число входит диапазон int, например 32 то можно без 'L' long n=32; в любом учебнике на первых 50 страницах описывают данные ситуации

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Целочисленные литералы по умолчанию относятся к типу `int`, а числа с плавающей точкой - к типу `double`. Поэтому для того чтобы инициализировать `long` или `float`, нужно добавить суффикс `L` или `F`.

```
long n = 100000000000000L
float m = 123.45F
```